# Xcode https call to Restful API

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios8

I am having an issue in making a call to our RESTful API. The request is to get the token from the API; I need that token to use it to make further calls on that API.

The issue is that whenever I make that call, I get HTTP 403 status code and I don't know why. I am making the same calls from Android but they work fine without any issue.

Actually I have no experience at all to work with xCode; I am just implementing some changes in the existing code which was written by some other developer. I don't know if I am doing something wrong or what.

```
  id keys[] = {@"grant_type", @"client_id", @"client_secret", @"username", @"password"};
  id objects[] = {@"password", @"AppClientID", @"AppClientSecret", @"usernamehere", @"userpasswordhere"};

  NSUInteger count = sizeof(objects)  / sizeof(id);
  NSDictionary *d = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys count:count];

  NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:d options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];

  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://oauth-test.websitename.com/token"];

  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:60];

  [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

  [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
  [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

  [request setValue:@"Basic" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
  [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];

  [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
            queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
             completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
             NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {

                 if(data.length > 0 && connectionError == nil)    {
                     NSLog(@"Response --> %@ ", response);
                 }
             }
   ];
```

Can someone try to help me figure out what is actually going wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should use URLSession because NSURLConnection is deprecated in iOS 10

Comment: will it solve my issue? or it is just a suggestion?

Comment: it is a suggestion and you can try it

Comment: Could you show the result of the log ?

Comment: Thanks Phu Duy! your suggested solution worked.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and the log, i am getting is

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1003 "A server with the specified 
hostname could not be found." UserInfo=
{NSUnderlyingError=0x608000059aa0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork 
Code=-1003 "A server with the specified hostname could not be found." 
UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://oauth-
test.websitename.com/token, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://oauth-
test.websitename.com/token, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, 
_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12, NSLocalizedDescription=A server with the 
specified hostname could not be found.}}, 
NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://oauth-test.websitename.com/token, 
NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://oauth-test.websitename.com/token, 
_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, 
NSLocalizedDescription=A server with the specified hostname could not 
be found.}
```

I tried it with NSUrlSession also but it is giving same problem.
I think your server is not configured

Below is the code with URL session

```
id keys[] = {@"grant_type", @"client_id", @"client_secret", 
@"username", @"password"}; id objects[] = {@"password", @"AppClientID", @"AppClientSecret", @"usernamehere", @"userpasswordhere"};

NSUInteger count = sizeof(objects) / sizeof(id); NSDictionary *d = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys count:count];

NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:d options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://oauth-test.websitename.com/token"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:60];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

[request setValue:@"Basic" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"]; [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];

NSURLSession * session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
NSURLSessionDownloadTask *dataTask  = [session downloadTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSURL * _Nullable location, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", response);

}];

[dataTask resume];
```

Comment: Yes, i am sure my code will not be reaching the server. I changed the URL as well as the actual values in object[]. But yes, I am now trying with NSURLSession as per suggested by you and Phu Duy

Comment: What i am tell you is,  Above is the code for NSUrlSession.  I think there is a problem with you link. If you can provide me some other like i can try with that.